# How to add Data to Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to add +1 every day to a global variable in Firebase to track how many days have passed. I'm building an app that give new facts every day, and at the 19:00 UTC time marker, I want the case statement number (the day global day variable) to increment by +1.

Some have suggested that I compare two dates and get the days that have passed that way. If I were to do that, I could hard code the initial time when I first want the app to start at 19:00 some day. Then when the function `reached1900UTC()` is called everyday thereafter, compare it to a Firebase timestamp of that current time which should be `19:00`. In theory, it should show that 1 day or more day has passed.

This is the best solution so far, thanks to @DavidSeek and @Jay, but I would still like to figure it out with concurrent writes if anyone has a solution in that front. Until then, I'm marking David's answer as the correct one.

How would I make it so it can't increase more than +1 if multiple people call this? Because my fear is that, when say, 100 people calls this function, it increases by + 1 for every person that has called it.

My app works on a global time, and this function is called every day at 19:00 UTC. So when that function is called I want the day count to increase by one.

Comment: why don't you just use NSDate? For example if you want it to count from today, use the current Date as a timestamp and then count the Dates between timestamp and the new current Date?

Comment: Like you said. If you would have 100 people to use your app and every one is calling a function at 19:00 that puts a global variable +1, then it would be +100

Comment: Same kind of issue arises though I believe. Lets' say I compare the two time stamps, and if 24 hours has passed, add +1. Would that not add + 1 for everyone?

Comment: see my answer. i think i have answered that question as well

Comment: The simplest solution is to keep a node with two children: *counter* and *last_updated*. When a user logs on it compares the date in last_updated with today's date and if it's not today, then increment the counter. If it is today, don't increment the counter. However...  Firebase has no server side logic so the whole thing depends on at least one user logging in daily; what if no users log in on a day, what then? You may want to re-think how you are tracking how many days have passed or even why that needs to be stored. Can each user track that on their device instead?

Comment: Let me update my question to give a better explanation of what i'm looking for and address good points that have been made.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39172057/6297658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to split your question into different sections.

1) If you want to use a global variable to count the days from, let's say, today. Then I would set a timestamp hardcoded into the App that sets the NSDate.

Then In my App, when I need to know the days that have been passed by, I would call a function counting the days from the timestamp to NSDate().

2) If you have a function in your App that counts a +1 into a Firebase, then your fear is correct. It would count +1 for every person that uses the App.

3) If you want every User to have a variable count since when they use their App, then I would handle User registration. So I have a "UserID" and then I would set a Firebase tree like that:

UserID
------->
FirstOpen
-------> Date

That way you could handle each User's first open.
Then you are able to set a timestamp AND call +1 for every user independently. Because then you set the +1 for every user into their UserID .child

Comment: My fear for this solution is using NSDate(), and working with people in different timezones and the ability for people to change their clocks. My thought is that I might get a firebase timestamp and compare it to a timestamp when the app opens. I think I might try working with concurrent writes first though and see if that can work. If I can't get the concurrent writing to work, i'll come back and mark your answer correct.

Comment: Well. I wouldnt worry much about different timezones. Since NSDate = NSDate. No matter if in my or your timezone. 24 hours are 24 hours. If you need everyone to use the same "clock", then I would hardcode an NSDate that uses the same timezone.

Comment: The only thing that you have mentioned is the thing about the possibility that people are able to change their iPhone's time. Then I would just handle a date from a server...

Comment: here you get a time based on a server side value. So no one can fake it by faking the iPhone time. handle this and you have the same time for every user. convert this api time into a string and save it into a UserID. child tree and compair it with the timestamp from the server api and you've handled every possibility

Answer (score 2):

You should use transactions to handle concurrent writes:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: I like this idea. I'm pretty new to firebase, is there a chance you could give me a code example?

Comment: @bradfordgray check out the link I provided. Code examples in both objC and Swift are there

Answer (score 2):

You may know this but Firebase doesn't have a way to auto-increment a counter as there's no server side logic, so having a counter increment at 19:00 UTC isn't going to be possible without interaction from a client that happens to be logged on at that time.

That being said, it's fairly straightforward to have the first user that logs in increment that counter - then any other clients logging in after that would not increment it and would have access to that day's new content.

Take a look at [Zapier.com](https://zapier.com) - that's a service that can fire time based triggers for your app which may do the trick.

As of this writing, Zapier and Firebase don't play nice together, however, there are a number of other trigger options that Zapier can do with your app while continuing to use Firebase for storage.

One other thought...

Instead of dealing with counters and counting days, why not just have each day's content stored within a node for each day and when each user logs on, the app get's that days content:

```
2016-10-10
      fact: "The Earth is an Oblate Spheroid"
2016-10-11
      fact: "Milli Vanilli is neither a Milli or a Vanilli. Discuss."
2016-10-12
      fact: "George Washington did not have a middle name"
```

This would eliminate a number of issues such as counters, updates, concurrent writing to Firebase, triggers etc.

It's also dynamic and expandable and a user could easily see that day's facts or the fact for any prior day(s)

Comment: A lot of good things to think about. I've heard of Zapier, i'll have to do some more research into them. Your idea with the nodes is a good one. Certainly simplifies things. Unfortunately I already @Davids solution to work. Regardless though, thank you for adding to the discussion and providing me with another solution.