# Wrong time since.. from timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I added timestamp to Firebase database formatted like: `1476700050.83933`.

So I wanted to calculate the time since this timestamp was created however as an output I get something like this: `1969-12-31 23:32:04 +0000`.

It sees somehow correct but how I am able to convert it now to like 5 minutes ago, etc.

I am doing my calculations like this:

```
let timestamp = postsArray[indexPath.row].timestamp//query timestamp from Firebase
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp! )//Readable date
let timeSincePost = (NSDate().timeIntervalSinceNow-NSDate().timeIntervalSince(date as Date))//Calculate time since
print("TimeSince", NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeSincePost))
```

I went trough many similar questions in many languages but they are all so different. Am I doing it very wrong?

Comment: Look at my question here:- http://stackoverflow.com/q/39171135/6297658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate().timeIntervalSinceNow` return value close to `0`.

`NSDate()` — creates date with current timestamp, you can call it `now`.
`timeIntervalSinceNow` here will be difference between time of creating data and method call, miniscule value.

So this:

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSinceNow-NSDate().timeIntervalSince(date as Date)
```

Can be seen like this:

```
0 - now.timeIntervalSince(date as Date)
```

For all dates in past `now.timeIntervalSince(date as Date)` is positive, and `0 - positive = negative`

And in the end you're subtracting time interval from January 1st, 1970 and get your date of 1969. Btw, why are you doing this?

Also, stop using `NSDate` in Swift 3, just use `Date`.

And use [`this method`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1410206-timeintervalsince) for `timeSincePost` calculation.

> how I am able to convert it now to like 5 minutes ago etc...

Just use `DateFormatter` with [`doesRelativeDateFormatting`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter/1415848-doesrelativedateformatting) set to true and get `stringFromDate` with original date you got with Firebird timestamp.

Comment: I am doing it because I want to get time since post on feed :)

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp, but i can't connect `time since post on feed` and `timeIntervalSince1970`. You already have number of seconds since post date, why do you need to relate it to 01.01.1970?

Comment: What do you mean in your answer with `"now."?` And to answer your question.. Like this I should get time since posted timestamp or I am wrong? What is your suggestion then?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp, `now` is now, current time, when `NSDate()` is called you get timestamp of current moment. And suggestion is in answer, after citation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with:

```
let timeSincePost = (NSDate().timeIntervalSinceNow-NSDate().timeIntervalSince(date as Date))//Calculate time since
```

You subtract the specified date from the current time, which for example results in 5 seconds. Then with:

```
print("TimeSince", Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeSincePost))
```

you are 5 seconds from the origin. Which is the problem you are experiencing.

---

NSDate has the [`timeIntervalSince(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1410206-timeintervalsince) method to get the difference between two dates. Saves a manual computation:

```
let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(date)
```

This gives the difference in seconds. To figure out the number of days and minutes etc use [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents). See [this](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/01/29/how-to-work-with-dates-and-times-in-swift-part-two-calculations-with-dates/) for a useful guide on how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirement, so added a date extension for this:

```
public extension NSDate {
   public func elapsedTimeString(toDate: NSDate? = NSDate()) -> String {

    let distanceBetweenDates = toDate!.timeIntervalSinceDate(self)
    let minutes = distanceBetweenDates / 60

    switch minutes {
    case 0..<1:
        return "now"
    case 1..<60:
        return "Int64(minutes) mins ago"
    case 60..<(60 * 24):
        return "Int64(minutes / 60) hour(s) ago"
    case (60 * 24)..<(60 * 24 * 7):
        return "Int64(minutes / (60 * 24)) week(s) ago"
    default:
        // somehow the date is ahead? so consider it now
        if minutes < 0 {
            return "now"
        }
        return "Int64(minutes / (60 * 24 * 7)) week(s) ago"
    }
   }
}
```